# AndEngine - one textureAtlas for all textureRegion in a scene; possible?

Tags: android, andengine

I noticed that I can keep one atlas for one textureRegion although I can draw same region multiple times as a sprite. Is it possible to keep all textureRegions in one textureAtlas in a scene?

My special case is, I am generating images instead of using any image file. I do this with BaseBitmapTextureAtlasSourceDecorator and generate the region from IBitmapTextureAtlasSource.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Generally, though, you should only create atlases with a a max width/height of 1024 (these sizes must be powers of 2, by the way), to be efficient.

On another note, I've found it easier to use BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas.  With this kind of atlas, you don't have to specify where in the atlas you are placing your textures.  I think it also might take care of sprite-bleeding to some degree (not sure, though).  It's the same idea really...  Here is an example from my project:

```
BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas buttonAtlas = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(getTextureManager(), 512, 512, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA); 
model.moveLeftButtonTR = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(buttonAtlas, this, "moveleft_button.png");
model.moveRightButtonTR = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(buttonAtlas, this, "moveright_button.png");
model.handleBlockButtonTR = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(buttonAtlas, this, "handleblock_button.png");
model.restartButtonTR = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(buttonAtlas, this, "restart_button.png");

try{ buttonAtlas.build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(0, 1, 1)); }
catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
buttonAtlas.load();
```

In your case, use the following method:

```
BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromSource(BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas atlas, IBitmapTextureAtlasSource source)
```

In summary, the atlas just holds all the textures you add to it.  Then you load this atlas into memory so that these textures can be retrieved quickly.  You can then use a single instance of a texture to build as many independent sprites as you wish.

Comment: In case of createFromAsset it works but in my case I have to createFromSource because I am not using any existing image file, I'm generating bitmap source (IBitmapTextureAtlasSource).

Comment: however, there is a method: BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromSource(...)

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm talking about. The regions created by this do not seem works for BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas.

Comment: Hmm. BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromSource(...) takes in a BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas source and a IBitmapTextureAtlasSource. Isn't that what you need?

Comment: But your answer is helpful. I just can't rank it up because I still don't have that privilege.

Comment: I just tried it, and my version of andengine has that method... I'm not sure why your's does not.

Comment: Ya, now it works! I didn't notice you edited your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, today I tested it, although it doesn't show compile error or any kind of other errors in logcat but the texture doesn't show up, instead white box appears.